# Alternative ways to merge two arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm merging a couple of arrays like this in PHP

```
//all the other stuff
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$json = json_encode($sxml);
$jObj = json_decode($json);

$new = new stdClass(); 
foreach ($jObj->entry as $entry) {
    $s = new stdClass();
    $s->title = $entry->title;
    $s->id = $entry->summary; 

$new->entries[] = $s; 
}
$array1 =  (array) $new;

foreach ($jObj->entry as $entry) {
      $urls[] = $entry->id;
    }

//$podcast_ids = [];
//$info = [];
foreach ($urls as $string) {
    if (preg_match('/id(\d+)/', $string, $match)) {
        $podcast_ids[] = $match[1];
    }
}
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?' . http_build_query(['id' => implode(',', $podcast_ids)])));

$info = new stdClass();
foreach ($json_array->results as $item) {
    $t = new stdClass();
    $t->artistName = $item->artistName;
    $t->feedUrl = $item->feedUrl;
    $t->primaryGenreName = $item->primaryGenreName;
    $t->artworkUrl60 = $item->artworkUrl60;

    $info->entries[] = $t;
}
$array2 =  (array) $info;
$ab = array('a' => $array1, 'b' => $array2);
print_r($ab);
```

`print_r($ab)` gives me something like this:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [entries] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [title] => Serial - This American Life
                            [id] => Serial is a podcast from the creators of This American Life, hosted by Sarah Koenig. Serial unfolds one story - a true story - over the course of a whole season. The show follows the plot and characters wherever they lead, through many surprising twists and turns. Sarah won't know what happens at the end of the story until she gets there, not long before you get there with her. Each week she'll bring you the latest chapter, so it's important to listen in, starting with Episode 1. New episodes are released on Thursday mornings.
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [title] => This American Life - This American Life
                            [id] => This American Life is a weekly public radio show, heard by 2.2 million people on more than 500 stations. Another 1.5 million people download the weekly podcast. It is hosted by Ira Glass, produced in collaboration with Chicago Public Media, delivered to stations by PRX The Public Radio Exchange, and has won all of the major broadcasting awards.
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [title] => Real Crime Profile - Real Crime Profile
                            [id] => Podcast talking about criminal cases and personality profiling.
                        )

                )

        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [entries] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [artistName] => This American Life
                            [feedUrl] => http://feeds.serialpodcast.org/serialpodcast
                            [primaryGenreName] => News & Politics
                            [artworkUrl60] => http://is2.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music69/v4/70/c9/71/70c97133-f3a8-738e-ea2c-27a6dc7d9731/source/60x60bb.jpg
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [artistName] => This American Life
                            [feedUrl] => http://feed.thisamericanlife.org/talpodcast
                            [primaryGenreName] => Personal Journals
                            [artworkUrl60] => http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music4/v4/1f/b8/0f/1fb80f69-bd94-8cad-0a2f-b082541d5f64/source/60x60bb.jpg
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [artistName] => Real Crime Profile
                            [feedUrl] => http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:202076064/sounds.rss
                            [primaryGenreName] => History
                            [artworkUrl60] => http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music69/v4/e4/0d/1e/e40d1efe-f625-8d15-4e2e-706fecead1e8/source/60x60bb.jpg
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This is close to what I'm looking for, but ideally, I'd like to simplify this even more so I don't have an `a` and `b` "tree" within this array. Is there a way to combine these to make one array instead of two arrays within one large array?

EDIT

This is what I'm trying to end up with:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [entries] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [title] => Serial - This American Life
                            [id] => Serial is a podcast from the creators of This American Life, hosted by Sarah Koenig. Serial unfolds one story - a true story - over the course of a whole season. The show follows the plot and characters wherever they lead, through many surprising twists and turns. Sarah won't know what happens at the end of the story until she gets there, not long before you get there with her. Each week she'll bring you the latest chapter, so it's important to listen in, starting with Episode 1. New episodes are released on Thursday mornings.
                            [artistName] => This American Life
                            [feedUrl] => http://feeds.serialpodcast.org/serialpodcast
                            [primaryGenreName] => News & Politics
                            [artworkUrl60] => http://is2.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music69/v4/70/c9/71/70c97133-f3a8-738e-ea2c-27a6dc7d9731/source/60x60bb.jpg
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [title] => This American Life - This American Life
                            [id] => This American Life is a weekly public radio show, heard by 2.2 million people on more than 500 stations. Another 1.5 million people download the weekly podcast. It is hosted by Ira Glass, produced in collaboration with Chicago Public Media, delivered to stations by PRX The Public Radio Exchange, and has won all of the major broadcasting awards.
                            [artistName] => This American Life
                            [feedUrl] => http://feed.thisamericanlife.org/talpodcast
                            [primaryGenreName] => Personal Journals
                            [artworkUrl60] => http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music4/v4/1f/b8/0f/1fb80f69-bd94-8cad-0a2f-b082541d5f64/source/60x60bb.jpg
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [title] => Real Crime Profile - Real Crime Profile
                            [id] => Podcast talking about criminal cases and personality profiling.
                            [artistName] => Real Crime Profile
                            [feedUrl] => http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/soundcloud:users:202076064/sounds.rss
                            [primaryGenreName] => History
                            [artworkUrl60] => http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music69/v4/e4/0d/1e/e40d1efe-f625-8d15-4e2e-706fecead1e8/source/60x60bb.jpg
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Does [array_merge](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php) work for you?

Comment: `array_merge($ab['a'], $ab['b'])`. You've got some absurdly overcomplex code here, too.

Comment: What is the goal you're trying to accomplish? You want an array and you're not requesting an array from `json_decode`...That feels odd. Why the need for all these `stdClass`'s?

Comment: Furtheremore, I think the question is worded too complex. Please elaborate how your two array you want to merge look like by what criteria. The way you build the arrays here seems out of scope of the question and is a chore to read through.

Comment: @ceejayoz Not sure exactly where to put the line you suggest. Tried after `$ab = array('a' => $array1, 'b' => $array2);`, but this didn't work. This totally left out everything from `$array1`. And yes, I know the code is complex, it's a horrible Frankenstein monster of cutting and pasting, but not quite experienced enough to optimize it yet.

Comment: @k0pernikus Sorry for the complexity. Trying to be comprehensive. I added an edit that shows the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried PHPs [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)?

`$ab = array_merge($array1, $array2);`

You may also be looking for output like this:

`$ab['entries'] = array_merge($array1['entries'], $array2['entries']);`

Comment: The first option only yields an array with `$array1`. It just ignores `$array2`. The second one merges them together in one array, but instead of having (for example) 2 entries with 4 different attributes, I get 4 entries with 2 attributes. That is, they don't really merge together under the same child.

Comment: Thats because I answered before your edit, where you actually explained what you were looking for.

Comment: However, the solution should be obvious by now - you just need to loop through the inner parts of each `entries` array and merge their contents into one single sub array. Im not going to code that out for you, look at the comments under your question - the whole script is a bit too cumbersome and convoluted, so a specific solution would be just as convoluted. You want to refactor that procedure for elegance first.

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP **7.4** it's possible to use the array spread operator for merging *(non string-keyed)* arrays:

```php
$array_1 = ['foo', 'bar'];
$array_2 = ['baz', 'qux'];
$array_unpacked = [...$array_1, ...$array_2, ...['quux']];
// ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux'];
```

As of PHP ***8.1*** it's possible to use the array spread operator for merging string-keyed arrays:

```php
$array = [...['a' => 'foo'], ...['b' => 'bar']];
// ['a' => 'foo', 'b' => 'bar'];
```

https://php.watch/versions/8.1/spread-operator-string-array-keys